# Will the story be drastically different depending on the house I choose in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I've chosen Gryffindor as my house and I'm enjoying the story so far, but how much different will the story be if I had chosen a different house such as Slytherin, Ravenclaw or Hufflepuff?

Are there even any differences? If yes, then what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only a few differences in the game that come about as a result of selecting one house over another. The most obvious, yet least impactful on the story are as following:

- The House Colors incorporated into some of your gear will reflect
  your chosen house
- Exclusive access to your Common Room location (and a Floo Flame fast travel point not accessible to other houses)
- Extra socializing and introductions with other 5th year students in your house
- Certain extra dialogue that may reference your house

The more impactful is the quest that leads up to meeting a certain individual part way through the storyline. Each house has a different quest that precedes the meeting with

> Richard Jackdaw

**Gryffindor:**

> Gryffindor students will embark on The Hunt for the Missing Pages, where you'll meet Nearly Headless Nick and join the Headless Hunt.

**Ravenclaw:**

> Ravenclaw students start the hunt for Ollivander's Heirloom, where you'll investigate The Owlery.

**Slytherin:**

> Slytherin students will become Scrope's Last Hope, which includes Following a series of map clues to meet Headmaster Black's House Elf and find a secret grotto.

**Hufflepuff:**

> Hufflepuff students seek out a Prisoner of Love, including a trip to the infamous Azkhaban Prison to solve a murdery mystery.

Besides that, there aren't really any differences to the storyline between each house.

---

[IGN Wiki: House Differences](https://www.ign.com/wikis/hogwarts-legacy/Which_House_Should_You_Choose#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20houses%20you,matter%20which%20house%20you%20choose.)

Comment: So the main story line is exactly the same on all of the houses?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt aside from the one quest leading to the meeting of the individual i mentioned, all other quests should be the same no matter the house you pick.